# Qt3Support and mingw static linker error

Tags: qt, linker, mingw

I had a problem at first compiling Qt static on windows, [QTBUG-11249](http://bugreports.qt.nokia.com/browse/QTBUG-11249?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel)

> When configured with "-no-qt3support", the build completes fine.

i did that and compiled successfully, but i get the same errors when i try to compile my application.

> e:\Qt\2010.04-static\qt\lib/libQtGui.a(qapplication.o):qapplication.cpp:(.text+0x8e0f): undefined reference to `_imp___Z21qt_call_post_routinesv' 
>   e:\Qt\2010.04-static\qt\lib/libQtGui.a(qapplication.o):qapplication.cpp:(.text+0x9443): undefined reference to`_imp___Z21qt_call_post_routinesv' 
>   e:\Qt\2010.04-static\qt\lib/libQtGui.a(qapplication.o):qapplication.cpp:(.text+0x9a6b): undefined reference to `_imp___Z21qt_call_post_routinesv' 
>   e:\Qt\2010.04-static\qt\lib/libQtGui.a(qwhatsthis.o):qwhatsthis.cpp:(.text+0xfc): undefined reference to`_imp___Z21qDeleteInEventHandlerP7QObject'

i'm using the mingw version packed with qt, when i use the shared qt dir it works, but when i try to link against the static one it fails.

now i guess it has something to do with -no-qt3support, but i have no idea how to use that in my project.

Comment: Did you find solution for your problem? I'm getting the same undefined reference, because I first added "-no-qt3support" with shared building. After the build was ok, I planned to compile the qt3support module, just for the sake, and seems that compilation is ok, but linking is not.